# SQL Query doubts from sample code

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to understand this sample code, and it would be a great help if you guys can explain how the $_GET function is retrieving data in the example below.

```
function _addLog($Device, &$output)
{
   if(isset($_GET['Speed']))
   {
       $query =
       "INSERT INTO Log SET"
       ." Device = ?"
       .", LogDateTime = ?"
       .", PositionDateTime = ?"
       .", Lat = ?"
       .", Lng = ?"
       .", Speed = ?"
       .", Angle = ?"
       .", Log.InOut = false"
       .", Code = ?"
       .", Message = ?";
```

Can any one explain to me the part of the code where $_GET is used to get those values?

```
   $params = array(
                    $Device,
                    date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    $_GET['PositionDateTime'],
                    $_GET['Lat'],
                    $_GET['Lng'],
                    $_GET['Speed'],
                    $_GET['Angle'],
                    $_GET['Code'],
                    $_GET['Message']);
                   addObject($query, $params, $output);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It can't be both mysql and sql-server. Also, which programming language is it? please add appropriate tags.

Comment: what's the status of this post? You were asked something in a comment and some answers. Plus, where and how are the GET's coming from? or are you asking us to do it/explain it for you?

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET` variables store the data passed to your `php` through GET requests. This can be a form submitted from HTML as shown below:

```
<form method='get' action='some_file.php'>
 <input tye="text" name="name">
 <input type="number" name = "age">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In `some_file.php`:

```
<?php

 $name = $_GET['name'];
 $age = $_GET['age'];
 /*
  Some more processing here
 */
?>
```

Here, `$name` holds the value whatever was entered in "name" input text box form on `HTML` page. Same holds good for `$age` as well.

Also, we can pass `GET` request parameters to `php` through URLs:
For e.g consider below URL: `http://abc.xyz.com/some_file.php?name=Tom&age=10`

This request `URL` supplies the values "Tom" and "10" for `$_GET['name']` and `$_GET['age']` respectively to the `php`

Comment: never submit a form using get. use post

Comment: @dean there's nothing wrong with a GET method. Many times, GET is required, plus they're using a prepared statement, so there's no issue here.